# What are those horizontal arrows on every line of code? How would I turn it On/Off?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

[image]

There are tiny arrows pointing out to the code on every line of code. What are those?

Comment: These are tabs, turn them off via Menu -> View -> Render Whitespace

Comment: How do I get those particular arrow shaped tabs?

Comment: Either by pressing the tab key or by some auto formatter. The arrows are just a way to display those tabs. For spaces you get dots if you look closely.

Answer (score 2):

These are the symbols for tabs. We use tabs or spaces to create indentation, it's somewhat a holy war [topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaces-what-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e).

Use the VSCode setting `"editor.renderWhitespace"` to turn it off entirely or partially.

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Studio 2022

Via Menu: `Edit > Advanced > View White Space`

Shortcut: `Ctrl + E, S`.